# Laggy Magic Mouse with Macbook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, mouse

I've had my Magic Mouse for about two weeks with a MacBook Pro 13", and I'm starting to notice quite a latency in the movement.

It gets really bad whenever any performance heavy operation is going on, that creates almost a half a second latency. This happens even for small things, like when a web page is being rendered, sometimes even while nothing is happening.

At first I thought batteries might've caused this, even though it was at 50%, so I changed them for new ones, which (subjectively) helped for about two hours, but it's still really laggy.

I also tried using the mouse on different surfaces, again it seems to work a little better on the table than on my mouse pad, but it's a little laggy everywhere.

Is this behavior normal for the Magic Mouse?

edit: I've been using my Macbook with 24" LCD at 1920x1280 resolution. When I plugged out the monitor, it seems that the mouse runs much more smoothly, even when I run applications like Photoshop.

Could the external monitor be causing such performance lag? But on the other hand, when I use it with USB mouse Logitech G5 there is no lag, not even on the 24" ...

Comment: what's your mouse pad and table's color? (might sound silly, but optical/laser mice require darker surfaces that can reflect the light back). A mouse pad with weird graphics was ok for "ball" mice, but some colors in the design may cause the signal to be disrupted, therefore causing lag and erratic behavior.

Comment: mouse pad is pure black and table is light wood color ... but I've been using Logitech G5 on the same pad for about 4 years with no problems.

Comment: No.  It is slow, and insensitive, but not laggy.

Comment: If it's at all possible, take your mouse and computer to the nearest [Genius Bar](http://www.apple.com/retail/geniusbar/). They can help you test both your computer and the mouse to figure out the culprit, and get the issue resolved.  It's most likely not something you can resolve yourself.  As a temporary workaround turning off WiFi may work, as WiFi and Bluetooth use the same frequency ranges.

Comment: I have the same problem; I am using a Macbook pro (i5 2,3 ghz), with Mac OS X Lion (10.7.2) and an external monitor. For me, the remedy was to switch off the wifi signal and use a cable to the router; it is certainly not the best workaround. Is there any better solution?

Answer (score 3):

I've had the same issue, starting with a late release of Snow Leopard, and now with Lion. The mouse works fine for a while and then it gets really laggy. Turning the mouse off (disconnecting bluetooth with the computer) and turning it back on fixes the problem, but it has happened at least a dozen times in the past week or so.

I've reported it as a bug to Apple, but it is hard to reproduce. I also have a MacBook Pro with an external monitor. I'm not sure if that is just coincidence, though.

Comment: This is just a comment not an answer :/